# Is it legal to have multiple HTTP GET parameters with the name?

Tags: html, http, get, standards

Is it "legal", according to the HTTP protocol, to make an HTTP GET request that contains multiple parameters with the same name?

For example `/controller?name=John&name=Patrick&name=Jack`

I'm sure different clients and servers react differently, however I am asking best practices, for example if you were to write a new server from scratch, or a new browser, client or whatever code that writes or parses HTTP requests: how should you handle such requests?

Is it allowed? In which case what is the interpretation?

Or is it non-standard?

Same question for POST applies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From HTTP's point of view, it doesn't matter - it doesn't put /any/ restrictions on what is in the query part of a an HTTP URI.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is perfectly legal, and there are many systems that take advantage of this.  Interpretation is up to the server and server-side code.